# How to Overlap a Div on Specific Location of Image using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, html, overlapping

I have an Large Image on Web Page. And a div Below it containing Data. Now, When User Clicks on Button the Div containing Data Must be Overlapped on Image on Specific Location using JQuery.

```
<div>
<img src="Images/FLRegions.png" usemap="#planetmap" style="height: 766px; width: 776px;z-index:1;" class="map" />
</div>

<div id="destination">
This div contains Data which must overlap on Image on specific Location using JQuery
</div>
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You need to set the css on `id=destination` to `position: absolute; left: x; top: y; z-index: 2;` and the css on the image to `position: relative;` when the user clicks the button. This is the only way to overlap a div, or any other HTML element for that matter. You will also need to put the destination id inside the div containing the image or it won't know what to overlap on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the div inside the other like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="Images/FLRegions.png" usemap="#planetmap" style="height: 766px; width: 776px;z-index:1;" class="map" />
    <div id="destination">
        This div contains Data which must overlap on Image on specific Location using JQuery
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS like this:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}
#destination{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

It can be moved dynamically with jQuery like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#destination').animate({
        left: 0, //enter your position
        top: 0  
    }, 500);
});
```